# Can I assign an array of pointer objects = another object?

Tags: c++, pointers

Say I have a building floor with a certain amount of rooms. Each room is empty.  I want to give an empty room a type. I have an office type in mind that is already created and I want to give the first available empty room that office type.

```
Room* availableRooms[max] {};
```

```
Office* mOffice = new Office;
// Values to mOffice are set later so it's not nullptr

for (int i = 0; int i < max; i++) 
{
    if (availableRooms[i] == nullptr) // If room is empty set it to the mOffice object
    {
        [i] = mOffice;
    }
}
```

Would this be the right way of doing it?

Comment: you will want a clean way to deallocate the pointers, and also if many rooms point to the same `mOffice` pointer you will have a huge aliasing problem and it will affect the deallocation process as well

Comment: The assignment becomes much safer if `Office` is a class derived from `Room`.

Comment: Just make sure you keep in mind ownership priviledges. (Who is responsible for the pointers)

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Room>> availableRooms(max);` would make life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Office` is a subtype of `Room` this should work, but you'd want to `break` after the assignment, otherwise **all** the empty rooms will point to `mOffice`, not just the first one:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; int i < max; i++) {
    if (availableRooms[i] == nullptr) {
        availableRooms[i] = mOffice;
        break;
    }
}
```